Split Test with VWO using URL parameters
Say I want to test users that have a specific parameter in their URL :
https://example.com/pre?q1=2&c1=67
Anyone with c1=67 passed in should then be redirected to a 50/50 split test. How can this be achieved?
I tried using "URL Matches Pattern" with this regex:
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/pre[?&]?.*c1=67.*

And then passed in this as an "editor url" for my control/variations:
https://example.com/pre/?affId=nva&uid=934&c2=223&c1=67
But i get the error :

Campaign did not run for visitor due to "Matching test page pattern"

Thanks

Please note that the regular expression does not work with the URL Matches Pattern option. Since you wish to run a split URL test, you can create a pattern like this for the Control URL using the URL matches pattern option:
https://www.example.com/?*c1=67*, here, the asterisks before and after "c1=67" will take care/consider any other query parameters coming before or after "c1=67" in the Control URL.
Similarly, for the Variation, you can keep the URL pattern as URL matches pattern https://www.example-1.com?*, here, the asterisk will consider the query parameters being forwarded from the Control URL and additional query parameters getting added to the Variation URL.
You can also refer to the below articles for information on how the query parameters are handled in split URL tests and different URL patterns in VWO:
https://help.vwo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020441674
https://help.vwo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021127714
